# BASH , for loop subtracting a number

Tags: bash, for-loop, decrement

In BASH ,

I'm trying to create a for loop that subtracting a number by 2

( lest say that number=8  , so I'd like to print 6, ,4 , 2 )

What is wrong with this syntax ?

```
 for (( $number; $number>= 0;$number --2));
do  
  
   echo "$number"
 done
```

`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

number=8
dec=2

for ((i=$number-$dec; i>0; i=$i-$dec)); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Output:

```
6
4
2
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
for (( number=8; number>= 0; number=number-2))
do
  echo "$number"
done
```

Output:

```
8
6
4
2
0
```

but if you only wanted 6, 4, 2, you'd need to change the range:

```
#        here v          v and here
for (( number=6; number>=2; number=number-2))
...
```

Another syntax would be:

```
$ for number in {6..2..2}
  do         
    echo "$number"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to save characters writing `((number=number-2))` you could do

```
for (( number=8; number>0; number-=2)); do
   echo "$number"
done
```

Be aware of the context, it can go wrong:

```
number=8
while (( number-=2 && number>0 )); do # Example of Wrong use 
   echo "$number"
done
```

For this solution you need additional parentheses

```
number=8
while (( ((number-=2)) && number>0 )); do
   echo "$number"
done
```

These parentheses makes it very error prone, so do not use it. I upvoted the solution of @Cyrus.